# In background application will wait for the incoming call

Tags: iphone, ios, background, app-store

I have requirement

1) when application start the send to background by launching any other app like open url in safari.

2) when it will go into background then it will wait for incoming call.

I have done first one and after so much R&D i get that in background our app will alive for 10 minutes after that it will auto kill. So how do second ne point?

This is app not for jail-broken device. And according to apple rules what methods i can use?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Is that call from your specific number or any phone call?
After receiving call what you want do in your application?.

But application does not receive any notification when it is in background,except push,local notification and handling URLS

Comment: @SanjeevRao any phone call. when any change occur in call log then show a local notification when click on ok button then show our app and interact with that number.

Comment: But there is no way to get call Log notification.
And even local notification will be created before your app going to background, you can not create them, when the app in background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Core Telephony Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009603).

And [CTCall Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCall/Reference/Reference.html) / [CTCallCenter Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCallCenter/Reference/Reference.html)